# Conda Pytorch on Windows results in HTTP Connection Error

Tags: anaconda, httpurlconnection, conda, pytorch, http-error

In general, my package manager and connection work fine. I just ran a `conda update --all` command that worked and updated all of my packages. However, when I run `conda install -c pytorch pytorch` as specified on anaconda's website https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch it results in the following error.

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64/pytorch-0.4.0-py36_cuda80_cudnn7he774522_1.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

I was curious if anyone else is experiencing this problem, as you may notice the pytorch upload for windows was only made on conda 3 days ago. Otherwise, if someone has a fix that will be compatible with conda, your input is appreciated.

UPDATE [SOLUTION]: I went to work and found an additional conda upload command for pytorch has been recently updated for windows. That is `conda install -c soumith pytorch` as specified https://anaconda.org/soumith/pytorch

I found this command to work on both my home and work laptops.

Comment: Seems like error from package. Have you tried submit issue to pytorch's authors? Maybe they can help you to figure out the causes. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/new